# Jquery live function suddenly not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using jQuery `live()` function to detect when the user was pressing some special keys (arrows, etc.):

```
$('.TextBox1').live('keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // ...
    }
});
```

It was working fine for a couple of months when suddenly yesterday it stopped working, preventing every line of JS code below it from executing. I have tried to replace it with the `.keyup` function but this has not helped. What could have happened?

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Did anything else happen yesterday? I bet it did.

Comment: [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and was removed in 1.9. Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: @Jon, yes, I had to replace the jquery link from http://code.jquery.com to the one from ajax.googleapis.com (apparently the latest), because it wasn't loading. If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I assume you've updated to the latest version of jQuery? `live()` has been deprecated since jQ1.7, and is now removed as of 1.9.

Instead, you should use `on()` with a delegate parameter:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.TextBox1', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //...
    }
});
```

Note that for best performance you should replace `document` in the above example with the closest parent element of `.TextBox1` which is not dynamically appended to the DOM after page load.

Comment: Getting 7 'almost the same' answers, im choosing this as the right one since it was the first.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery .live is deprecated.
Although not strictly the same, use .on()
For your example it would look like:

```
$('body').on('keydown', '.TextBox1', function() {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.live()` was removed after jQuery 1.9.

You have to use `.on` from now on.

Answer (score 2):

.live was removed in jQuery 1.9. If you are calling the lastest version of jQuery it will break.

Change your code to use .on

Answer (score 2):

`.live()` was removed in the latest version of jQuery 1.9.

You can use the [jQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) instead, or change the code to use `.on`.

Answer (score 1):

use this as mentioned on jquery site.
for your example it will be

`$(document).on( "keydown", ".TextBox1", function() {
});`

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Read this for more information about [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

live has actually been removed on jq 1.9, not just deprecated! you can use the plugins for compatibility or update your code to on

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` deprecated in jq 1.9 so you can try this

```
$('.TextBox1').on('keydown', function() {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i guess i was the only one not knowing about it. XD

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the jquery to 1.7?

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

Use .on() to attach event handlers:

```
$('.TextBox1').on('keydown', text_box_key_down_function);
```

You can also use bind:

```
$('.TextBox1').bind('keydown',text_box_key_down_function);
```

Answer (score 0):

.live was removed when JQ 1.9 was released, so I guess you have updated Jquery to the lastest.

Now, try:

```
$('.TextBox1').on('keydown', function() {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.live was removed when JQ 1.9 but now there is solution for run both .live and .on at the same time

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

[More about Jquery migrate](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/)

[Feather information from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882731/how-to-use-jquery-migrate-plugin)