# How to make a jquery script compatible with jquery 2.x.x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use [this](http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/#home) multi-level push menu in my webapplication. But the problem with this plugin is that it needs an older version of jQuery. It will crash in combination with v2.x.x of jQuery.

The owner has done this on purpose, so that older browser versions are covered with the plugin as well.

So I'd like to convert/migrate this script to make it compatible with the latest version of jQuery, the only problem is, is that jQuery isn't my 'thing' (yet). I'm not sure where to start, what to remove of what to add in the script.

My question basically is, can someone point me into the right direction to get this script working with the latest version of jQuery?

I'd really really appreciate any help!

Comment: This could help you: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Comment: have you tried jQuey 1.11? it has the same API as 2.1 but supports older browsers

Comment: how about the jQuery NoConflict? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: @micnic, it seems that the only version push menu wants to work with, is version 1.10.2. I tried the 1.11.3, but I get the same crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

**UPDATED ANSWER**:

Use **Version2** from the Multilevel Push Menu download page! [::link::](http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/download/MultiLevelPushMenu_v2.1.4.zip) ...

I downloaded that version, and changed from jquery-1.10.2 to jquery-2.0.3 ... and it's **working perfectly!** Here's a jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/vLrp51g3](https://jsfiddle.net/vLrp51g3)

---

*PREVIOUSLY ANSWERED*

*As suggested by `A. Wolf`, you can use migrate jquery js file to handle the older jquery version. Since the remaining plugins/scripts of your webpage might require latest jquery, you could use the getScript() function to load the migrate jquery for only the pushmenu plugin! Therefore, you should probably use the code provided below for your requirement...*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript( "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js", function() {
        $.getScript('js/jquery.multilevelpushmenu.min.js', function() {

            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu();

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What about jQuery 2.1.4? Doesn't that have to be included as well?

Comment: Sorry... I just read more on [migrate jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882731/how-to-use-jquery-migrate-plugin), and found that it doesn't affect the plugin at all! Although, I haven't tested it myself, you could try adding the migrate script right after the jquery-2.1.4 script... using `<script src=>` tags...

Comment: I have tried that, didn't work. So this leaves me to adjust the plugin itself. Do you have any suggestions on what to change for it to be compatible with the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: Use Version2 from the Multilevel Push Menu download page! [::link::](http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/download/MultiLevelPushMenu_v2.1.4.zip) ... I downloaded that version, and changed from `jquery-1.10.2` to `jquery-2.0.3` ... and it's working perfectly! Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLrp51g3/

Comment: I was using the latest version of v2 branch. And I was testing everything again this morning. Went from `jquery-1.10.2` to `jquery-2.1.4` and all works perfectly!? Something else must be causing this, i'll do some more debugging. If you could update your answer containing your comment, I'll mark it as answered. I thank you very much `M`ortal `K`ombat (character nr:) `117`!